# Сортировка файлов по папкам на bash

Tags: bash, сортировка

Есть папка, содержащая кучу файлов вида: `randomname-year-month-day.log`
Как прогнать их всех через цикл, и для каждой группы файлов создать свою папку и поместить их туда.
Сортировать файлы нужно группами по `year-month` - так же назвать и саму папку, в которую они должны быть помещены.
По итогу работы скрипта вместо кучи файлов в папке должно быть несколько папок вида `year-month` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы к сожалению не привели реальных имен файлов, не понятно какие именно случайные части у них в начале. Вам надо будет сделать такой фильтр `sed` что бы он выделил из имен файлов составляющую для названия каталога, т.е. год и месяц. Из предположения, что в случайной части нет больше частей `-NNNN-NN` получается примерно такой скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `ls -1 *.log | sed 's/.*-\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/' | uniq`
do
 mkdir $f
 mv *-$f-*.log $f/
done
```

Сначала вам надо отладить ту часть, которая в обратных апострофах, она должна выдавать список уникальных имен каталогов, т.е. месяц-год. И при желании поправить пути в командах. Приведенный скрипт переносит файлы из текущего каталога в подкаталоги создаваемые в нем же.

```
До выполнения a.sh:

$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mike mike 122 Dec 30 22:07 a.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike mike   0 Dec 30 21:58 fdfdfn-2015-08-03.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike mike   0 Dec 30 21:58 sdfdnfd-2015-08-01.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike mike   0 Dec 30 21:58 sdfnskdf-2015-09-02.log

После выполнения:
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 mike mike 4096 Dec 30 22:16 2015-08
drwxr-xr-x 2 mike mike 4096 Dec 30 22:16 2015-09
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mike mike  122 Dec 30 22:07 a.sh

$ ls -l 2015-08
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike mike 0 Dec 30 21:58 fdfdfn-2015-08-03.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike mike 0 Dec 30 21:58 sdfdnfd-2015-08-01.log
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, Mike! Ваш ответ очень помог мне! Хотел еще уточнить - не подскажете, как можно исключить из цикла файлы, которые созданы в день выполнения скрипта? Что-нибудь вроде (ls $backup_dir | grep -v `date +%F`) Не знаю только как правильно указать выборку - до применения цикла. Или возможно ее можно засунуть внутрь цикла.

Comment: сделал вот таким образом `for f in `ls -1 $path/*.log | grep -v \`date +%F\` | sed 's/.*-\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9][0-9    ]\).*/\1/' | uniq`
` - по логике вроде правильно, но проблема работы в кавычках)

Comment: `find $path/*.log -mtime +1` - дата последней модификации 24 часами ранее текущей

Comment: Причем find можно использовать уже внутри цикла, что бы каталоги обойти все, но переносить только "старые" файлы: `find log/*.log -ctime +1 -exec 'mv' '{}' '$f/' ';'`